# C++ register function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

i need a help to register a function from my application to a lib and can use it in lib later. The function is a singleton one.

This is how i want to send it like:

```
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) RegisterFunctionsLib(const std::function<void(int, const std::string&)>& func_1, const std::function<void(const std::string&)>& func_2);

RegisterFunctionsLib(
    CMySingletonClass::Instance().NameFunction, // not works
    NormalFunction, // works
);
```

And in my lib project looks like:

```
void RegisterFunctionsLib(const std::function<void(int, const std::string&)>& func_1, const std::function<void(const std::string&)>& func_2)
{
    func_1(1, "func_1");
    func_2("func_2");
}
```

The func_2 works, because is a normal function, not singleton and other things, but the functions which are from singleton class, not working. < error on compilers.
Thanks.

Comment: Singletons are evil. They are basically just global variables (with all the pain that entails). Their initialization / construction order is only guaranteed within a single translation unit, so you already have problems there. Once you try to use them in libraries you have even more problems. The *solution* IMO is; *never use singletons*. They are an anti-pattern and *will* bite you eventually. Just don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to bind a member function to a specific instance, you can't just pass a member function as though it is a normal function pointer - the two things are quite different. A member function effectively consists of two things - an instance and a function. Fortunately lambdas can solve this specific issue really well.

I did not test this because your example is not complete so I can't compile it, but you could do something like this:

```
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) RegisterFunctionsLib(const std::function<void(int, const std::string&)>& func_1, const std::function<void(const std::string&)>& func_2);

CMySingletonClass* psingleton_inst =  CMySingletonClass::Instance();
RegisterFunctionsLib(
    [psingleton_inst](int i, const std::string &str){psingleton_inst->NameFunction(i, str);}
    NormalFunction, // works
);
```

Where you capture a pointer to a singleton instance and then in your lambda you can call the instance function directly. The lambda type then matches the std::function since it takes an `int` and a `const std::string &`. Assuming , of course, you are using c++11 or higher

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried but it doesn't work, i get Error 7 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals. Also i changed:
 CMySingletonClass* psingleton_inst = &CMySingletonClass::Instance();

Comment: @Dr.Vendetta your example is incomplete so I can't really do so much to debug that for you. Here is an example I knocked up roughly following what you are trying to do: https://godbolt.org/z/2v5Wqy

Comment: Thank you so much! It's worked! Can you give me your paypal email in private or something or how can i contact you? I would like to send you some money for it, friends and family. Please. You helped me a lot, i'm trying since 2 days.

Comment: @Dr.Vendetta well, that's very kind of you, but people have helped me here just as much and then you can help the next person ... I will settle for an upvote and a tick ; )